# intelliJ not picking up classes inside JAR files

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maven, intellij-idea

I have been trying for a while to get intelliJ to pick up classes inside JAR files. Please could you help me.

On the left hand side you can see that it is successfully there as a libary/dependency but I cannot use any classes inside the JAR file.

Do I need to unpack it?

Many thanks,

[image]

Comment: If you use maven - you should add a maven dependency to your pom. Can you show us your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Do you using jar files in your library? Have you add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in your `dependencies` ? From you image, it seems that it cannot find the `mapView` which I think you have wrong package name. It should be `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`, you can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html)